# Fetching Data from JSON using jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, json

Currently am trying to fetch data from an JSON to my SelectBox.

Here I show its XML format, but the actual data will be in JSON format:

```
<1>
   <book_able>0</book_able>
   <CODE>AF</CODE>
   <NAME>Afghanistan</NAME>
</1>

<2>
   <book_able>1</book_able>
   <CODE>AL</CODE>
   <NAME>Albanie</NAME>
</2>

<3>
   <book_able>1</book_able>
   <CODE>DZ</CODE>
   <NAME>Algerie</NAME>
</3>

<6>
   <book_able>1</book_able>
   <CODE>AS</CODE>
   <NAME>Samoa Americaines</NAME>
</6>
```

Here the numbers denote the order of the countries. But the numbers are not correctly ordered.

For Example: After `<1>` the next number is `<198>`, so it's hard to fetch using a loop. Is there a method for this in jQuery and JSON?

Comment: You give us the JSON in XML for "easy understanding" ?

Comment: Please make it harder for me to understand by adding the actual JSON

Comment: You should not be using a loop to fetch the data by number. Since the number is the key of each JSON item, you should be able to write `myJSONString.198` or `myJSONString[198]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose your parsed object is like this :

```
var obj = {
    "1": { book_able:0, code:"AF", name:"Afghanistan"},
    "2": {
    ...
}
```

with no reason for the keys to be "ordered" : JavaScript gives no guarantee regarding object key iteration order.

Then you can change this map to a real array like this :

```
var arr = [];
for (var i=1;; i++) {
    if (!obj[i]) break;
    arr[i] = obj[i];
}
```

Note that you'll mainly get a `length` by doing this, as you yet could access your original object using `obj[i]`.